# Is it possible to achieve identical performance with either react.js or jQuery + AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, dom, single-page-application

I understand that React uses virtual DOM and uses an efficient diff algorithm to calculate the delta and then finally propagate the same to the actual DOM to re-render (only the altered component and NOT the entire DOM).  Is it not possible to do similar re-rendering of only the necessary component with AJAX? So where does React.js really win? Kindly correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misunderstanding React.

React is a javascript library to build user interfaces. 
With React, you break your interface in small pieces called Components. These components are reusable and you can compose them to make complex UIs.

A comparison between Ajax and React doesn't make any sense, since their purposes are different. You can (and probably will) use Ajax with React to make your requests. Some popular libraries to do that are [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and the browser built-in [window.fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).